# convert letters to integer and then find sum of a string

Tags: c++, c

I am learning programming languages and require help to understand logic of scenario where i am taking a `string` as input, replacing all letters with numbers like (a=0,b=1,c=2) and then sum up and finally display it.

ex: if string is "abcd" then output should be 0+1+2+3=6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `switch` statements FTW!

Comment: There's an example in "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritche that shows you how to do this.

Comment: Hint: [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Use ASCII. it should look something like 'for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(str) ; i++)
{
sum+= (str[i]-'a');
}

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather not post a complete solution because then it'd miss the whole "i am learning programming languages" point (unless you're into "copying HW answers from SO" and I assume you're not :) )

- The ASCII codes of letters are continuous chunks between 65-90 and 97-122 for capitals and non-capitals respectively
- If you're using an actual `string` (makes sense since it's tagged `c++`) you should read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) about accessing a specific character in a string (which is the same as with an array but the point is to begin getting acquainted with the various documentation\man pages).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    const char *string="abcd";
    unsigned sum = 0;
    while(*string)
        sum += strcspn("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", (char [2]){ *string++ });
    printf("%u\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have used std::string and iostreams, since its tag c++. And wouldn't name a variable "string". . strcspn is a nice trick.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY for letting me know this trick.wasn't aware of it.